# Complex-valued event horizon of a Kerr black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, kerr-metric

The Kerr metric has two physical relevant surfaces on which it appears to be singular. Solving the quadratic equation $1/g_{rr} = 0$ yields the solution:

$$r_H^\pm=\frac{G M}{c^2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{G M}{c^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{J}{M c}\right)^2}$$

What happens when the radicant gets negative such that the horizon gets a complex number? Do we have to choose a different coordinate system in this case?

Answer (score 2):

That means that there is no real value that solves the horizon equation, and the Kerr hole ceases to be a black hole and becomes a naked singularity.

There is an active conjecture, called the cosmic censorship hypothesis, that says that there is no process that starts from "ordinary matter" that can produce such an object.

Comment: That is hard to believe. (+1)

Comment: @kaffeeauf: if you want a little more of a heuristic, the temperature of the black hole, per normal black hole thermodyanics arguments, is proportional to that radical.  So, the point at which the term under the radical becomes zero is the point at which the black hole has zero temperature, so the third law of thermodyamics would imply that you can't get to there, much less beyond there.